# Redirect change made to a variable to another variable

Tags: variables, aliases, variable-watchers

I have variables `foo` and `bar`. I have a function that modifies `foo` and I can't change that function.

How can I *redirect* the change made to `foo` so it applies to `bar` instead?

EDIT :

I want this redirection to track real time change.

What I am trying to achieve :

I want to swap the headerline with the modeline.
I did this with this snippet of code :

```
(defvar og-modeline mode-line-format)
(setq-default mode-line-format header-line-format)
(setq-default header-line-format og-modeline)
```

It works well but when something from an other package makes change to the headerline it obviously uses `header-line-format` but I want instead those change to be done to `mode-line-format`. Thus why I ask if there is the possibility to redirect changes.

Comment: I get the feeling somehow that this is an [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: It is, but I don't know how to do it in elisp and, maybe I should have add this bit of explanation : I need this to remind active whenever there is a change made to foo or bar

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Only one question per post, please.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific in your question. As @NickD hinted, try asking something (much) closer to what you are actually wanting to do.

Comment: excuse me @Drew, I have edited the question with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this section of the manual: [Running a function when a variable is changed](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Watching-Variables.html)

You pass a function to `(add-variable-watcher 'mode-line-format #'my-watch-function)`, and that function gets passed various attributes of the variable when it changes.